# How I can find out that swapchain image presentation (not command submission) was already done?

Tags: vulkan

I can have the most trivial sample code like this:

```
void drawSomething()
{
  checkForFence(m_inFlightFences[m_currentFrameIndex]); // Check if images of current index were submitted (Fences were created signaled, to pass first method entrance).

  // Get next swapchain image to copy to.
  m_device->acquireNextImageKHR(swapchain, UINT64_MAX, m_imageAcqSem[m_currentFrameIndex], vk::Fence());

  // Enqueue commands.
  vk::SubmitInfo submitInfo{ wait for m_imageAcqSem[m_currentFrameIndex] and some other stuff... };
  m_presentQueue.submit(submitInfo, m_inFlightFences[m_currentFrameIndex]); --> !!!Here it starts to be wierd for me.

  // Present on display
  m_presentQueue.presentKHR(semaphore to wait for, checking that submit was done, and some other stuff, but no fence possible here...)

  m_currentFrameIndex = (m_currentFrameIndex + 1) % m_swapchainImages.size();
}
```

**How I can know that the presentation itself was done and not just the command submission, when the fence** (I have an array of fences of a swapchain image size, so it is not one that is waited immidiately) **is asociated with queue submission?**

Because if I understand it properly the call that returns the image to the swapchain is `presentKHR`, so it can happen, that I try to obtain with the `acquireNextImageKHR` the image of the index, that is still in use and was not returned yet, but the fence is already promising that re-usage is possible, as it is asociated with submission call, that could already be possibly executed.

Is the only solution to check out the result of `acquireNextImageKHR` and if it does not retrieve success, to try to fix all the stuff around?

*NOTE: I am using Vulkan-hpp, so some calls have sligtly different naming, but the logic should be same.*

*All synchronisation primitives like semaphores, fences are in collections of a size of swapchain image count to avoid unnecessary waiting.*

Comment: Actually is just checking for the result of presentKHR enough? As i understand it - this result code is not saying that presentation was done, but that it is was successfully enqueued. But by the common logic then it should mean that if `acquireNextImageKHR` was enqued on the same queue after the `presentKHR`, then it should be done in *correct order*, but how I can find out the queue, where `acquireNextImageKHR` is enqueued, as in call itself the execution queue is not specified...

Answer (score 0):

When you call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR()` the image you get back may still be in use by presentation engine. To synchronize the surface access you need to provide the `semaphore` and/or the `fence` parameters to `vkAcquireNextImageKHR()`. Those sync objects will be signalled by the presentation engine when it's released the image for reuse.

Comment: But this is the thing. The `vkAcquireNextImageKHR()` has just the semaphores/fences to signal, not to wait for. This however is not the problem, as I can wait for fences in `checkForFences`, but then the problem I see is the fact, that this fence is signaled by queue submit call and not the present call as presentKHR cannot signal any fence or semaphore. So long story short - the submission is signaled, but not the presentation itself and if I got docs, the swapchain image is released by PRESENTATION and not by submission.